# Подскажите со структурой хранения и группировки свойств идентичных для всех элементов инфоблока

Tags: битрикс

У одного элемента инфоблока на сайте выводятся различные характеристики

- пример 1 https://villa-premantura.com/ru/accommodation/villa-byanka/ - к одному дому привязаны различные характеристики
- пример 2 http://locust-russia.ru/catalog/mini-pogruzchiki-locust/locust-753/ - к одной модели техники привязаны различные характеристики

По заданию надо разработать структуру для хранения и группировки данной информации. Вариант создавать отдельное свойство для каждой характеристики - не рассматривается. Использовать надо только штатный функционал инфоблоков.

Помогите пожалуйста в обычном режиме создал бы таблицу с характеристиками и потом связывал бы в другой таблице каждый объект с каждой характеристикой (многие ко многим), но как это делать в битрикс с использованием инфоблоков понять не могу(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В битриксе есть возможность организовать свойства по аналогии многие-ко-многим, для этого при создании свойства элемента нужно установить галочку "Множ."

[image: Создание свойства]

Далее, если требуется организовать у каждой характеристики значения "параметр - значение", в настройках создаваемого свойства нужно установить галочку "Выводить поле для описания значения"

[image: Настройки свойства]

В итоге это позволяет создать структуру для хранения характеристик как из второго примера. Естественно, каждую характеристику нужно создать отдельно

[image: Вот так выглядит свойство в админке]

Если свойств много и они разнородны, есть возможность добавлять определенные свойства товаров только для определенных разделов ИБ, это делается в карточке редактирования раздела на вкладке "Свойства элементов".
Например, диагональ дисплея и плотность пикселей для планшетов и размер, цвет и ткань для футболок. Если правильно настроена карточка редактирования товара, то мы при редактировании планшета не будем видеть свойств размер и ткань (относящихся к футболкам) и наоборот, у футболок не будет диагонали и плотности пикселей. При этом одно и то же свойство может быть привязано к нескольким разделам, например, диагональ может быть и у мониторов, и у телефонов